# jquery-1.8.2.min.js disable drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching data from database using jquery in search bar as user enter some character in it will fetch data from database the search is working perfectly but it disable my drop down menus on the top and when i remove `jquery-1.8.2.min.js` from the page the search module stop working and drop down menus start working . i have tried `jquery-2.1.0.min.js` but did not get the result.Here is my coding.please help me out.

```
    <form action="view_cat.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="search" class="autosuggest" >

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/javascrip.js"></script>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
             var search_term=$(this).attr('value');
             $.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term},function(data){
                 $('.result').html(data);               
                 $('.result li').click(function(){
                 var result_value=$(this).text();
                 $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
                 $('.result').html('');
             });
             });
         });
     });
</script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

The drop down menus script.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var example = $('#sf-menu').superfish({
            delay:       400,
            animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},
            speed:       'fast', 
            autoArrows:  false
        });

    });
</script>
```

Please suggest me some Alternative path.

Comment: it seems to be other js library is causing this. also you can take a look how many libraries are there in your page.

Comment: sorry will you please explain me what i did wrong

Comment: Are there any other library other than this `1.8` version.

Comment: yes i am using a template

Comment: It seems, you missed out `<script></script>` tags around your jQuery code.

Comment: no i have done <script></script> tag

Comment: _yes i am using a template_...... explain more.

Comment: i have alot of javascript file but i am making this template fully dynamic

Comment: Can you provide an example of the dropdown markup/ library link?

Comment: ok let me see it will take little time to find out the jquery using for the dropdown menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using template than for sure I can say there should be another jquery file which are conflicting with each other please check out the file if you have another jquery file remove it and as far I am seeing your calling your jquery above the body so remove the jquery script from the bottom and put in the head section will work fine I hope.

Comment: yea i had more than one one jquery script in my template now as you said remove other script i did and is working fine thank Alot to All